# Limit returned rows per unique pyspark dataframe column value without a loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a quick question I hope someone can answer.

Is it possible to, within a pyspark dataframe, limit the amount of results a unique value in a certain column returns?

For example, I have a dataframe with 4 columns:

```
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|partner|productId         |    mediumtype|   prediction|
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|7005410|               544|             1| 0.0026476993|
|7005410|               549|             2|-2.6975607E-4|
|7005410|               626|             3| 2.0409889E-4|
|7005410|               840|             2| 3.6301462E-5|
|7005410|              1192|             3| 2.2148499E-5|
+-------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

The *partner* column has a numeric value (in this case *7005410*). In the example you see 5 rows with a unique *partner id*, but in reality there are 7.000+ unique partner id's. And this counts not only for this partner, but for all the other 4.000+ partners, meaning there are 7.000 * 4.000 = 28.000.000 rows in total.

What I want it to only fetch the top 5 predictions (limit(5)) for every unique partner id. So far I have put the dataframe in a loop with a filter but due to the lazy loading nature of Spark this takes a tremendous amount of time to complete, I was wondering if there is just a way to apply a limit(5) to every unique partner id.

Comment: when u say top 5 predictions, what r u ordering them by? or is ordering not imp n u only want top 5?

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi the predictions have been ordered by executing orderBy(['partner', 'prediction'], ascending=False). Meaning that the top prediction per partner always comes first. So in this case the ordering is not that important, just returning the top 5 rows per unique partner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Take **`row_number()`** over a **`window`** and filter out where ever **`rowNum`** is **`greater than 5`**. Considering data is already ordered, we can just orderby a literal constant in the window.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("partner").orderBy(F.lit(1))

df.withColumn("rowNum", F.row_number().over(w))\
  .filter('rowNum<=5').drop("rowNum").show()
```

Comment: Did not know you could 'col<=5' , nice!
how does it distinguish between a string or an int though? i.e. if I want to filter by a string condition

Comment: @Dee just add different quotes around it to denote string like `'col="aa"'` or `"col='aa'"`